# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named ... for Builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

I am getting error while implementing Caching (using Caffeine Cache) in an existing project.

Same code works fine for example application.
I know similar questions has already been asked but neither worked for me. I have implemented using this example: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-with-caffeine-cache/

Below are the code snippet:
EventListner Class:

**MyEventListener.java:**

```
 @Slf4j
    @Component
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class MyEventListener {
         @Autowired
         private final MySecurityServiceClient mySecurityServiceClient;
.
....some code
.
ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> tokenResponseResponseEntity =mySecurityServiceClient.getUserToken();
}
```

**MySecurityServiceClient.java:**

```
public interface MySecurityServiceClient {
    public ResponseEntity getUserToken();

}
```

Interface implementing class **DefaultMySecurityServiceClient.java:**

```
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class DefaultMySecurityServiceClient  implements MySecurityServiceClient{
     .
     ...some code
     .
    @Override
    @Cacheable("userToken")
    public ResponseEntity getUserToken() {
    .
    .
    .
 return responseEntity;
}
```

}

**application.properties**

```
spring.cache.cache-names=userToken
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=expireAfterWrite=120s
```

Also, I am using
**Caffeine Cache Version** = 2.8.5

**Spring Boot version** = 2.3.5.RELEASE

**Error:**

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'userToken' for Builder[public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.DefaultMySecurityServiceClient.getUserToken()] caches=[userToken] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver#resolveCaches` and see what are the Cache Names it resolved. You are probably using a different config file to run your app. Also, post the full stacktrace.